# How do I set a variable to the value of only one block in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a procedure that switch project between active and inactive: if the project is originally inactive ---- make it active. And vice versa. Projects and their states are saved in a table, the code should be like:

the table is called projectlist, it has two columns: project and state

@project is parameter

```
SET @State =SELECT state FROM projectlist WHERE project = @project
```

( I know this is wrong but I dont know the right way to do it)

```
IF @State = 'active'
Update ......

IF @State = 'inactive;
Update .....
```

Right now I just want to know how to set that @State to the state of its respect project so I can make a proper if statement.

Comment: select @state = state FROM projectlist WHERE project = @project; ?

Comment: Thank you... it works, im so dumb, I should just close this question

Comment: It's alright but you should have first checked MSDN document for right syntax. Anyways, now don't close the question ... LOL you understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be like below (right syntax)

```
SELECT @State = state FROM projectlist WHERE project = @project

IF @State = 'active' 
UPDATE ......
ELSE
DELETE .....
```